# Reveal a navigation component on one route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, components, react-router

I have an app with navigation at the top (Home, About, Faq). Only on HOME route I need the menu to be hidden and then reveal onscroll. Navigation is built in App.jsx so it appears on every single page. How do I enable the reveal for just this particular route?

My reveal component

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NavScroll extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={isHide:false};
      this.hideBar = this.hideBar.bind(this)
    }
    hideBar(){
       let {isHide} = this.state
       window.scrollY > this.prev?
       !isHide && this.setState({isHide:true})
       :
       isHide && this.setState({isHide:false})

       this.prev = window.scrollY;
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',this.hideBar);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
         window.removeEventListener('scroll',this.hideBar);
    }
    render(){

        let classHide=this.state.isHide?"hide":""
        return <div className={"fixed "+classHide}>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default NavScroll;
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavLink from './global/NavLink.jsx';
import Footer from './global/Footer.jsx';
import NavScroll from './global/NavScroll.jsx';


var App = React.createClass({



  render: function(){

    return (
      <div>
         <div>
          <NavLink to="/"><img className="logo" alt="HOME"></img></NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/about" className="navMenuButton">ABOUT</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/faq" className="navMenuButton">FAQ</NavLink>
        </div>

        { this.props.children }

        <Footer />

      </div>
    );
  }
});



export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check the `pathname` of the current [`location`](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v2.x/docs/Location.md). The `location` is an [injected prop](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props) of the component rendered for a matched route.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { location } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        { location.pathname === '/' ? <HomeNavigation /> : <OtherNavigation /> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I had to be more specific and use this.props.location instead, so it was:     const location = this.props.location;

Comment: `const { location } = this.props` is the same as `const location = this.props.location`, it just uses a destructuring assignment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring It isn't really necessary for only one variable, but it comes in handy when you want to destructure a number of variables from the same object.

Comment: Also, if this solves your problem, you can mark this as the correct answer.